# Serve different css based on browser width in css

Tags: html, css

I am unable to find this on Stackoverflow existing queries. Please help if this can be accomplished.
I want to capture browser with with mobile-first responsive design approach.
Depending upon the browser width, I want to include div's:

1) If browser max-width is 320px, then use ""`<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#configurator" data-width="***320***" data-numposts="5"></div><br>Floating box</div>`

2) If browser width is 480px or above, then use 
"`<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#configurator" data-width="**480**" data-numposts="5"></div><br>Floating box</div>`"

I am aware of using media-queries in CSS (like:

```
@media (min-width: 300px) {
  html { background: blue; }
}
```

but how do I use these for div's with changing values of width in div parameters (320 and 480)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that-I mean creating different width sizes, since you want to create a mobile responsive design why don't you try  [Twitter Boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)- arguably one of the best mobile-responsive framework-helps you to design your application and adapts it to any screen size. Moreover, this will help you to reverage on the expertise that's already in the framework.
I think you can learn it easily too.